# Issue during cv::gpu::SURF_GPU usage: ‘KeyPoint’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv

Here trying to use the opencv's class : SURF_GPU.

**testSURFGPU.cpp:**

```
#include <opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::gpu::SURF_GPU surf;

    return 0;
}
```

**Console command:**

```
g++ test_surf.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Following are the error messages when I compile :

**Console response:**

```
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:75:44: error: ‘KeyPoint’ was not declared in this scope
         void uploadKeypoints(const std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, GpuMat& keypointsGPU);
                                                ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:75:52: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         void uploadKeypoints(const std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, GpuMat& keypointsGPU);
                                                        ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:75:52: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:77:68: error: ‘KeyPoint’ was not declared in this scope
         void downloadKeypoints(const GpuMat& keypointsGPU, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints);
                                                                        ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:77:76: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         void downloadKeypoints(const GpuMat& keypointsGPU, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints);
                                                                                ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:77:76: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:98:72: error: ‘KeyPoint’ was not declared in this scope
         void operator()(const GpuMat& img, const GpuMat& mask, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints);
                                                                            ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:98:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         void operator()(const GpuMat& img, const GpuMat& mask, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints);
                                                                                    ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:98:80: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:99:72: error: ‘KeyPoint’ was not declared in this scope
         void operator()(const GpuMat& img, const GpuMat& mask, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, GpuMat& descriptors,
                                                                            ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:99:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         void operator()(const GpuMat& img, const GpuMat& mask, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, GpuMat& descriptors,
                                                                                    ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:99:80: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:102:72: error: ‘KeyPoint’ was not declared in this scope
         void operator()(const GpuMat& img, const GpuMat& mask, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, std::vector<float>& descriptors,
                                                                            ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:102:80: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         void operator()(const GpuMat& img, const GpuMat& mask, std::vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, std::vector<float>& descriptors,
                                                                                    ^
    /usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp:102:80: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

What I'm doing wrong? How an OpenCV's file (gpu.hpp) can't recognize an Opencv's object (KeyPoint)?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

*Setup:* Ubuntu 14.04, OpenCV 2.4.11

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an include for the cv::KeyPoint definition.

Try adding

```
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
```

to your demo code.

Comment: I already tried it, without sucess...
But _KeyPoint_ is not delcared in `/usr/local/include/opencv2/nonfree/gpu.hpp` not in my demo code. So, why should I need to add `#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>` in my code ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

So, I found a (the) solution, I needed to had:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
```

to my demo code.

Comment: If you take a look at the content of *cv.h* you'll see the following lines:


//CV_WARNING("This is a deprecated opencv header provided for compatibility. Please include a header from a corresponding opencv module")

#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/flann.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp"